# Intel WiFi is not detecting in Debian. Using Dell Inspiron 11 3147

Tags: debian, drivers

I just bought a laptop for school, and I decided to put Debian 8 on it through live usb. When I was installing, it could not detect the ethernet card at all, even though I knew iwlwifi should be the correct driver. I continued installation thinking I could install the driver later. I installed the driver from the debian package search by putting it on a usb drive and using `dpkg`. I rebooted, still didn't work. The WiFi device is a Intel 3165. Note that I cannot use fancy commands like `lshw` because I'm using a base install.

Note: I am using Mint Linux now, which works.

Comment: Please edit and add the output of `lspci | egrep -i  'network|ethernet'`

Comment: @GAD3R Sorry, but I decided to switch to Linux Mint, which worked. I can't give you it without having to reinstall.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to get `iwlwifi-firmware` and a kernel from backports.

Add a line like:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

The run `apt-get update` and install the package with `apt-get -t jessie-backports install iwlwifi-firmware`.

And do something similar for a kernel (I don't remember if there's a 4.6 in backports yet, or if you'll have to go for a 4.5).

Comment: I said that I have already installed that package manually, and it is still not working. I will try again, and I will tell you the outcome. I am not connected to the internet at all.

Comment: I have reinstalled the both the drivers and backport, and still nothing. I am keeping the downvote.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that you had installed iwlwifi, and not just knew you needed it, but note that I've completely changed the answer.